# Write vorbis comment metadata (tags) to the existing FLAC file using libFLAC++

Tags: c++, oggvorbis

How to write vorbis comments metadata, i.e. tags (for example "TITLE"), to the existing FLAC file using libFLAC++ ([http://flac.sourceforge.net](http://flac.sourceforge.net/))?

For example:

```
const char* fileName = "/path/to/file.flac";

// read tags from the file
FLAC::Metadata::VorbisComment vorbisComment;
FLAC::Metadata::get_tags(fileName, vorbisComment);

// make some changes
vorbisComment.append_comment("TITLE", "This is title");

// write changes back to the file ...
// :-( there is no API for that, i.e. something like this:
// FLAC::Metadata::write_tags(fileName, vorbisComment);
```

Comment: You have the source code available for the metaflac program, you should be able to figure it out (even if it's C).

Comment: If nobody answers then I will go that route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've analysed metaflac source code (as suggested) and here is a solution to the problem:

```
#include <FLAC++/metadata.h>

const char* fileName = "/path/to/file.flac";

// read a file using FLAC::Metadata::Chain class
FLAC::Metadata::Chain chain;
if (!chain.read(fileName)) {
    // error handling
    throw ...;
}

// now, find vorbis comment block and make changes in it
{
    FLAC::Metadata::Iterator iterator;
    iterator.init(chain);

    // find vorbis comment block
    FLAC::Metadata::VorbisComment* vcBlock = 0;
    do {
        FLAC::Metadata::Prototype* block = iterator.get_block();
        if (block->get_type() == FLAC__METADATA_TYPE_VORBIS_COMMENT) {
            vcBlock = (FLAC::Metadata::VorbisComment*) block;
            break;
        }
    } while (iterator.next());

    // if not found, create a new one
    if (vcBlock == 0) {
        // create a new block
        vcBlock = new FLAC::Metadata::VorbisComment();

        // move iterator to the end
        while (iterator.next()) {
        }

        // insert a new block at the end
        if (!iterator.insert_block_after(vcBlock)) {
            delete vcBlock;
            // error handling
            throw ...;
        }
    }

    // now, you can make any number of changes to the vorbis comment block,
    // for example you can append TITLE comment:
    vcBlock->append_comment(
        FLAC::Metadata::VorbisComment::Entry("TITLE", "This is title"));
}

// write changes back to the file
if (!chain.write()) {
    // error handling
    throw ...;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but man... have you ever peeked inside `FLAC::Metadata::VorbisComment::Entry`? It performs 3 memory allocations. One for the "key", one for the "value" and one for the entry itself (key=value). And all in a C-ish way. One day people will learn how far 1 std::string and 2 std::string_views can get them. For now I think I am going to prepare the entries myself and use the raw C version, as done in `FLAC_plugin__tags_set` (pretty much your code, only in C)